# How can i fix my json output?

Tags: json, curl

I have an issue to decode the json that i receive from CURL,
i used json_last_error to see what may be the reason and it looks like my json is malformed.

```
        // Make the REST call, returning the result
        $response = curl_exec($this->curl); // result is as per screenshot below

        $resp_json = json_decode($response, true);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($resp_json); // display nothing
        echo "</pre>";
```

[Click here to see the json output and the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xm5D.jpg)

from jsonlint, response is like...

```
{
    "RESPONSE_DATA": [{
                "property_address": "6\/192 Kingsgrove Road",
                "price": 0.0,
                "contact_name": "Nicholas Smith",
                "property_facing_direction": "unknown",
                "agent_name": "",
                "client_id": 46984,
                "property_suburb": "Kingsgrove",
                "agent_phone": "",
                "contact_phone": "0407 787 288",
                "ordered_datetime": "2017-12-05 04:15:03",
                "agent_email": "",
                "property_state": "NSW",
                "job_id": 2324,
                "im_job_id": "40432-o",
                "product_ids": 3000000,
                "confirmed_datetime": "",
                "photographer_comment": "Photography Premium Daylight 3 photos  $145.00\
                nAdd Per Premium Photo 2 at $20 .00 each\ n Total $185 .00 ","
                contact_company ":"
                Raine & Horne Commerical - Marrickville ","
                agent_id ":"
                ","
                preferred_datetime ":"
                2017 - 12 - 07 11: 00: 00 ","
                property_postcode ":0000,"
                status_code ":"
                N "}],"
                RESPONSE_MESSAGE ":"
                OK ","
                RESPONSE_CODE ":200}
```

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19981380/9041712

Comment: not really did not change anything, thanks

Comment: What is your response if you direct run `$ curl {URL}` in your terminal?

Comment: i have posted the json output, it's what return the site, so the json needs to be fixed. Just do not know how to fix this json so i can decode it as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 issues broking the json:

1. Unexpected newline
2. `\n` in `photographer_comment`
3. `\ n` in `photographer_comment`
4. `property_postcode ":0000`

That you can hardcode to replace it by:

```
$json = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $json));
$json = str_replace("\\n", "", $json);
$json = str_replace("\\ n", "", $json);
$json = str_replace(":0000", ":\"0000\"", $json);
```

It's quick and dirty, and not covering other cases; you can try regex if you want to use a more general way. But I think it would be more reasonable to fix it at the data provider side.

Besides above, some keys' name are not good due to the tailing empty space, such as: `"preferred_datetime "`

Comment: Thanks! However the issue is still there because of the line-breaks and the " after photographer_comment. check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I modify my answer, give it a try?

Comment: It works! Thanks, i contacted the server side IT guy to make his json fixed, however your solution works.